# How to run SQL Server Management Studio without loading Add-Ins

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have recently installed an Add-in for SQL Management Studio for intelisense/refactoring. It has caused my Management Studio to perform so slow that it is unusable. I have uninstalled the product, but it still appears to have affect Management Studio. Is it possible to run without any Add-ins enabled?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No guarantees, but since SSMS is built on a Visual Studio shell, you can try to hold down your left shift key while starting SSMS - this key press disables add-ins in Visual Studio.

Also have a look [here](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/jonsayce/archive/2008/01/25/uninstalling-an-ssms-add-in.aspx) for a registry trick.

Remove keys from:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Shell\AddIns
```

or

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Shell\AddIns
```